# JQuery animation moves on first click but not second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

In this code I am trying to make the word "About" and eventually the work "Portfolio" move all the way to the left, and then all the way back when the x button that I added in is clicked, or when the word is clicked a second time. I got the animation of moving the word all the way to the left but I can not get the animation where it moves back to work, either when the button is clicked, or when the word is. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
(Sorry for the long links, not able to put shortened ones in posts)

### https://jsfiddle.net/ngtef82y/

```
<div id='bckDrp'>
  <div id='nav'>
    <img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/media-and-navigation-buttons-round/512/Button_12-128.png' id='xBttn'>
    <ul id='navLst'>
      <li class='navOp' id='hme'>Home</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='abt'>About</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='prt'>Portfolio</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
var abtBack = function() {
  if ($('#abt').css('right') == 210) {
    $(this).animate({
      left: 210
    }, 450);
  }
}

var main = function() {
  //When any tab is clicked
  $('#hme, #abt, #prt').click(function() {
    $('#xBttn').toggle(300);
    $('#xBttn').click(function() {
      $('#xBttn').fadeOut(300);
      $('#hme, #abt, #prt').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 300);
    })
  })

  //When Home tab is clicked
  $('#hme').click(function() {
    if ($('#abt, #prt').css('opacity') == 0) {
      $('#abt, #prt').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 300);
    } else {
      $('#abt, #prt').animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, 300);
    }
  });

  //When About tab is clicked
  $('#abt').click(function() {
    if ($('#hme, #prt').css('opacity') == 0) {
      $('#hme, #prt').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 300);
    } else {
      $('#hme, #prt').animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, 300);
    }
    if ($('#abt').css('right') == 210) {
      $(this).animate({
        left: 210
      }, 450);
    } else {
      $(this).animate({
        right: 210
      }, 450);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

I decided to leave the css out, check jsfiddle for full code.

Comment: Before anyone recommends it I want to say that I already have thought of using .addClass and .removeClass to perform the same task, but I will only use that as a last result, as I would have to recode most of my Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is:

- save the left position of your about element before attaching the event
- inside the event handler check the left position against the saved one
- change the animation so that you go left in back or forward direction

```js
var abtLeft = $('#abt').offset().left;
//When About tab is clicked
$('#abt').click(function() {
  if ($('#hme, #prt').css('opacity') == 0) {
    $('#hme, #prt').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 300);
  } else {
    $('#hme, #prt').animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 300);
  }

  if ($('#abt').offset().left == (abtLeft - 210)) {
    $(this).animate({
      left: "+=210"
    }, 450);
  } else {
    $(this).animate({
      left: "-=210"
    }, 450);
  }
});
}
```

[Your updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngtef82y/2/)

Comment: that helped that the other part of the problem that I needed. I will have to research more about that .offset command. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Add `right: 0` to the animate in click function of the `#xBttn`

```
//When any tab is clicked
$('#hme, #abt, #prt').click(function() {
   $('#xBttn').toggle(300);
   $('#xBttn').click(function() {
      $('#xBttn').fadeOut(300);
      $('#hme, #abt, #prt').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        right: 0
      }, 300);
   })
})
```